# Difference between ngStorage and $window.localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, angular-directive, ng-storage

What is the difference between ngStorage and $window.localStorage? When is  it better to use one instead that the other? 
I have to choose one of them for a web app. I have to save data of profile user and the token

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This is normal html5 local storage:**

> With local storage, web applications can store data locally within the user's browser. Before HTML5, application data had to be stored in cookies, included in every server request. Local storage is more secure, and large amounts of data can be stored locally, without affecting website performance. Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never transferred to the server. Local storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from one origin, can store and access the same data.

It gives you to objects to access the storage - window.localStorage and window.sessionStorage

window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date

window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session, so data is lost when the browser tab is closed

To retrieve data you would do something like this

```
localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

So if you wanted to do this in angular you would use the $window service but it would behave the same as the examples above.

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

---

To address ngStorage:

> An AngularJS module that makes Web Storage working in the Angular Way. Contains two services: $localStorage and $sessionStorage. No dealing with getters and setters like you have to in $window service

You can pass $localStorage or $sessionStorage by reference under $scope:

```
$scope.$storage = $localStorage;
```

Then you can use $storage as and other angular variable

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <button ng-click="$storage.counter = $storage.counter + 1">{{$storage.counter}}</button>
</body>
```

[Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-storage)

---

If you will be working with angularjs in your webapp I would use ngStorage because you will be more comfortable and familiar with the syntax. That is just my opinion though.

Answer (score 8):

The variable `$window` usually is the global `window` variable. The reason that Angular recommends using `$window` is because sometimes you would like to mock or replace the "real" `window` object (for testing purposes, for example).

Said this, using `$window.localStorage` means that you are using the Local Storage's vanilla API, while ngStorage is

> An AngularJS module that makes Web Storage working in the Angular Way.
>   Contains two services: `$localStorage` and `$sessionStorage`

Source [here](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

Comment: More explicitly, ngStorage will take care of the serialization aspects for you, which can be a time-saver.

Answer (score 3):

Just be mindful ngStorage internally uses an Angular watch to monitor changes to the `$storage`/`$localStorage` objects i.e a digest cycle is required to persist your new values reliably into the browser's local storage. Normally not a problem but if you store a value in `$localStorage` and open a new tab without a digest cycle occurring, you might not be able to see the stored values in your newly opened tab/window.

Ran into this problem on IE and had to use `window.localStorage` to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var setLocalStorage = function (token, uname) {
  $localStorage.token = token;
  $localStorage.name = uname;
}
$timeout(setLocalStorage(token, userForm.uname), 500);
```

> Module Used : ngStorage

It works!